# freemark syntax error in keycloak theme ftl file

Tags: keycloak, freemarker

I modified login.ftl file in the keycloak theme then i got this error:
freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template "login.ftl" in line 100, column 1:
Encountered "/@layout.registrationLayout", but at this place only this can be closed: "#if". This usually because of wrong nesting of FreeMarker directives, like a missed or malformed end-tag somewhere.
then i rolled back the changes but the error didnt go away.

here is the code where the error is encountered:

```
<#if realm.password && social.providers??>
        <div id="kc-social-providers" class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountSectionClass!}">
            <hr/>
            <h4>${msg("identity-provider-login-label")}</h4>

            <ul class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountListClass!} <#if social.providers?size gt 3>${properties.kcFormSocialAccountListGridClass!}</#if>">
                <#list social.providers as p>
                    <a id="social-${p.alias}" class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountListButtonClass!} <#if social.providers?size gt 3>${properties.kcFormSocialAccountGridItem!}</#if>"
                            type="button" href="${p.loginUrl}">
                        <#if p.iconClasses?has_content>
                            <i class="${properties.kcCommonLogoIdP!} ${p.iconClasses!}" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <span class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountNameClass!} kc-social-icon-text">${p.displayName!}</span>
                        <#else>
                            <span class="${properties.kcFormSocialAccountNameClass!}">${p.displayName!}</span>
                        </#if>
                    </a>
                </#list>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </#if>
```

full error:

```
08:02:44,093 ERROR [org.keycloak.forms.login.freemarker.FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider] (default task-1) Failed to process template: org.keycloak.theme.FreeMarkerException: Failed to process template login.ftl
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.theme.FreeMarkerUtil.processTemplate(FreeMarkerUtil.java:71)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.forms.login.freemarker.FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider.processTemplate(FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider.java:512)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.forms.login.freemarker.FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider.createResponse(FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider.java:277)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.forms.login.freemarker.FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider.createLoginUsernamePassword(FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider.java:527)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm.challenge(UsernamePasswordForm.java:87)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.UsernamePasswordForm.authenticate(UsernamePasswordForm.java:73)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processSingleFlowExecutionModel(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:446)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:253)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processSingleFlowExecutionModel(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:389)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:276)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticateOnly(AuthenticationProcessor.java:990)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticate(AuthenticationProcessor.java:852)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.protocol.AuthorizationEndpointBase.handleBrowserAuthenticationRequest(AuthorizationEndpointBase.java:151)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.buildAuthorizationCodeAuthorizationResponse(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:300)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.process(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:183)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.AuthorizationEndpoint.buildGet(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:106)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:170)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:130)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:660)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$2(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:474)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:476)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:434)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:192)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:152)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:183)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:32)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:492)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@16.1.1//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:41)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:43)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@16.1.1//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: freemarker.core.ParseException: Syntax error in template "login.ftl" in line 100, column 1:
Encountered "</@layout.registrationLayout>", but at this place only this can be closed: "#if". This usually because of wrong nesting of FreeMarker directives, like a missed or malformed end-tag somewhere. (Note that FreeMarker end-tags must have # or @ after the / character.)
Was expecting one of these patterns:
    <ATTEMPT>
    <IF>
    <ELSE_IF>
    <LIST>
    <ITEMS>
    <SEP>
    <FOREACH>
    <SWITCH>
    <ASSIGN>
    <GLOBALASSIGN>
    <LOCALASSIGN>
    <_INCLUDE>
    <IMPORT>
    <FUNCTION>
    <MACRO>
    <TRANSFORM>
    <VISIT>
    <STOP>
    <RETURN>
    <CALL>
    <SETTING>
    <OUTPUTFORMAT>
    <AUTOESC>
    <NOAUTOESC>
    <COMPRESS>
    <COMMENT>
    <TERSE_COMMENT>
    <NOPARSE>
    <END_IF>
    <ELSE>
    <BREAK>
    <CONTINUE>
    <SIMPLE_RETURN>
    <HALT>
    <FLUSH>
    <TRIM>
    <LTRIM>
    <RTRIM>
    <NOTRIM>
    <SIMPLE_NESTED>
    <NESTED>
    <SIMPLE_RECURSE>
    <RECURSE>
    <FALLBACK>
    <ESCAPE>
    <NOESCAPE>
    <UNIFIED_CALL>
    <STATIC_TEXT_WS>
    <STATIC_TEXT_NON_WS>
    <STATIC_TEXT_FALSE_ALARM>
    "${"
    "#{"
    "[="
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.core.FMParser.generateParseException(FMParser.java:6120)
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.core.FMParser.jj_consume_token(FMParser.java:5979)
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.core.FMParser.If(FMParser.java:1828)
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:3629)
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.core.FMParser.MixedContentElements(FMParser.java:4019)
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.core.FMParser.UnifiedMacroTransform(FMParser.java:3009)
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.core.FMParser.FreemarkerDirective(FMParser.java:3664)
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.core.FMParser.MixedContentElements(FMParser.java:4019)
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.core.FMParser.Root(FMParser.java:4665)
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.template.Template.<init>(Template.java:252)
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.loadTemplate(TemplateCache.java:548)
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplateInternal(TemplateCache.java:439)
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplate(TemplateCache.java:292)
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2836)
    at org.freemarker@2.3.31//freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:2703)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.theme.FreeMarkerUtil.getTemplate(FreeMarkerUtil.java:85)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.theme.FreeMarkerUtil.processTemplate(FreeMarkerUtil.java:58)
    ... 93 more
08:02:44,094 ERROR [org.keycloak.headers.DefaultSecurityHeadersProvider] (default task-1) MediaType not set on path /auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth, with response status 500
08:02:44,094 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-1) Uncaught server error: javax.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.headers.DefaultSecurityHeadersProvider.addHeaders(DefaultSecurityHeadersProvider.java:75)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSecurityHeadersFilter.filter(KeycloakSecurityHeadersFilter.java:39)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.ContainerResponseContextImpl.filter(ContainerResponseContextImpl.java:361)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.executeFilters(ServerResponseWriter.java:252)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:101)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:74)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:594)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:261)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:364)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:164)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:247)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:60)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-core@4.7.4.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55)
    at javax.servlet.api@2.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@16.1.1//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:41)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@16.1.1//org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:43)
    at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@16.1.1//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@1.18.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.10.1.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:275)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:134)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@26.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1544)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:255)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:79)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:100)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
    at io.undertow.core@2.2.14.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:852)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.5.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: The template that you quote is balanced, so it shouldn't cause this. Though you say that you have rolled back and still the error persist, so I'm not sure if we are even looking at the right template. Like if you replace the template with just `<#stop "Just testing...">`, will it stop with the matching exception?

Comment: Were you able to fix this error?